# Conflicting Types in function

Tags: c, function, sqlite

This function has worked and compiled fine for the past few days however now is giving me and error that reads:

> "conflicting types for 'PrepareSQLRead'"

Below is the function that is having the issues,

```
sqlite3_stmt* PrepareSQLRead(sqlite3 *db, char* TableToRead){

int rc;
char SQL2[128];
sqlite3_stmt* SQL;
sprintf(SQL2, "SELECT * from %s", TableToRead);
printf("%s\n", SQL2);
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,SQL2,-1, &SQL, 0);
if (rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't prepare statement: %s\n",
            sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return NULL;
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Statement prepared successfully\n");
}


return SQL;}
```

I really don't understand why I am now getting this issue as I haven't even changed the function contents since it worked fine.

Comment: Did you remove a header file recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is telling you exactly what's happening - there is an implicit declaration of **PrepareSQLRead** because you don't declare explicitly before  `main()`. Might be add a forward declaration before main:

```
sqlite3_stmt* PrepareSQLRead(sqlite3, char*);
```